How to adjust taskbar "eject devices" text color in Windows 10
When using the systemwide dark mode in Windows 10, the text for the name of the device on the device eject menu is rendered gray on gray. (MyBook(K) in screen capture below)
How can I adjust the color of that text and make it lighter so it is more easily readable?
I have WinAero Tweaker, but I have been unable to find the correct setting.
What is the taskbar context menu for "device eject" called? Maybe I'm searching on the wrong term?

